# Are data part of a class or does the class group the data?

Tags: terminology

I've started learning Statistics for a couple days now. While trying to make flashcards, a part of me thought about the phrasing of a certain flashcard: Upper Class Limit (front) / the maximum number a class can have (back). After overthinking it for little bit, I changed it to 'the largest number that can be in a class.' Now I'm pondering. Should I be using an active voice or a passive voice to describe this?

Comment: I don't see a difference between the two, in terms of entailment. The first one might be a bit less formal-sounding, but that's it.

Comment: As long as **you** can understand what's on the back of the card, either version should be OK.